# Razor syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Consider this Razor syntax in JavaScript:

```
@{
   int badgeCount = ViewBag.badgeCount;
 }

<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i = 0; i < @badgeCount; i++) {
        TrackWonBadge('@CurrentMember.Name');
    }
</script>
```

I try to use badge count in the loop, but there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should go with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var badgeCount = Number('@ViewBag.badgeCount');

    for (var i = 0; i < badgeCount; i++) {
        TrackWonBadge('@CurrentMember.Name');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a better approach would be to try to keep dynamic JavaScript out of the picture as much as possible. Something like this would work better:

```
@{
    int badgeCount = ViewBag.badgeCount;
    string memberName = "Some Name";
}

<input type="hidden" id="BadgeCount" value="@badgeCount" />
<input type="hidden" id="MemberName" value="@memberName" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var badgeCount = document.getElementById('BadgeCount').value;
    var memberName = document.getElementById('MemberName').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < badgeCount; i++) {
        TrackWonBadge(memberName);
    }
</script>
```

This has the advantage that you will be able to migrate your script into its own file should it become more complex.

In fact, I wouldn't build a script inline at all. I'd move it to a separate .js file to keep the markup separated from your logic on the client side. This is similar to what ASP.NET MVC forces you to do on the server side; your view is using a separate language from your controller and is thus in a separate file. Even if you don't want to do that kind of file separation right now, writing dynamic JavaScript makes this eventual separation harder down the line as your code is in production and under maintenance.

Comment: I can't see the benefits of creating two useless hidden inputs.

Comment: Yes me too , I agree with gdoron

Comment: It would be separating your HTML from your JavaScript, which is a good practice in its own right. You could move your JavaScript into its own file. It separates your view from your logic. It is the same reason you use a code-behind file in classic ASP.NET instead of writing C# in `<script runat="server">` tags in your .aspx files. But do what you will.

Comment: Your answer isn't clear. I agree that you should move a script into it's own file, so why you're writing an inline script here? Other thing: you set the names to the hidden fields but trying to get them by id.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the names vs. IDs thing. For the other issue, I can only quote myself: "This has the advantage that you will be able to migrate your script into its own file should it become more complex." Basically, I was trying to nudge OP in the right direction without having him totally rewrite his code. I was trying to make the example more legible for him by using as much of his code as possible.

Comment: @Zabavsky: I edited it to make my intent more clear. Thanks for the constructive criticism.